# Is there any PDF reader like Foxit Reader, for Linux?

Tags: linux, open-source, pdf, reading

I have installed Foxit Reader in Fedora, using wine. I found a foxit Linux version, but it is not like the windows version, because there are many things that cannot be done, compared to the Windows version of Foxit.

I installed the windows version in Linux by using wine but it is not smooth as it was in Windows. It is working quite slowly.

Here i have mentioned some of the options that are not in foxit linux version.

- There is no ribbon. To change any option, I have to go to the menu every time.
- There is no stamp system. The stamp option of foxit is very important to me, especially the "Reviewed" stamp, because it takes the current time and date, which helps me to track which page was read when.
- There is no window splitting option. It is very useful when I need to work with multiple pages of the same book.
- There is no quick toolbar to access the most used options quickly.

These are the points I'm facing problems with.

I want to know if there are any PDF readers in Linux that will give me all the features I listed above. Possible dependencies on a certain desktop (KDE, LXDE etc.) are not an issue, as I have them all installed.

Comment: @Izzy i have installed all the desktops and use them as i need one's certain feature....Desktop is not a problem.But Cinnamon makes problem for sometime.All is acceptable..

Answer (score 1):

Tried [Master PDF Editor](https://code-industry.net/free-pdf-editor/)? Though it's not open source (only noticed the tag months after first answering), and it looks like it uses a mostly paid-only model except for Linux  that still has a "Free for non-commercial use" version (hidden on their website very well, *after* the "download for Linux" link) it's still the best PDF editor for Linux I've found.

(For Windows & Mac there's a *"demo version [that] allows you to try all features of Master PDF Editor.
There is no limitation except for the addition of a watermark on output file."*  But often with linux it comes down to *I'll take what I can get*, using either foss, freeware, trial, paid, other, WINE, or another OS in a virtual PC - generally preferred in that order).

You could add your own "reviewed" marks or timestamps (or any other comments for that matter). It appears to have no shortage of toolbars, and says it has these features:

- Edit PDF text, images and pages with full editing features
- Create new PDF or edit existing ones.
- Add and/or edit bookmarks in PDF files.
- Encrypt and/or protect PDF files using 128 bit encryption.
- Convert XPS files into PDF.
- Add PDF controls (like buttons, checkboxes, lists, etc.) into your PDFs.
- Import/export PDF pages into common graphical formats including BMP, JPG, PNG, and TIFF.
- Split and merge PDF files.
- JavaScript support.
- Dynamic XFA form support.
- Validation Forms and Calculate Values.
- Adding a digital signature and Signing PDF Documents.<sup>**1**</sup>
- Fast and simple PDF forms fill out.
- Changing font attributes (size, family, color etc).

The [paid version](https://code-industry.net/masterpdfeditor/) is available with the full feature set (the above is not complete), while the Linux [free version](https://code-industry.net/free-pdf-editor/) for non-commercial use (for example personal / educational use) has the following features locked:

- "Paste to Multiple Pages"
- "Save Optimized As..."
- "Document Actions"
- "Document JavaScript"
- "Page Properties"
- "Signing PDF with digital signature"

[image: screenshot]
<sup>Screenshot (click to enlarge)</sup>

---

Or there's plain [Evince](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Evince), it's FOSS and usually a part of Gnome's standard software.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup></sup><sub>Only available in the [paid version](https://code-industry.net/masterpdfeditor/) (~EUR 50). See the bottom of the [free download version](https://code-industry.net/free-pdf-editor/) for other locked features.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Try [Qoppa PDF Studio](https://www.qoppa.com/pdfstudioviewer/download/).

It has Similar tool bar UI as Foxit on Windows.

[image]